# c variadic function misbehaviour

Tags: c, ubuntu, variadic-functions

I'm compiling very simple program on Ubuntu-14 32bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void test(char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    printf(fmt, args);

    va_end(args);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    test("%u\n", 123);
    printf("%u\n", 123);
    return 0;   
}
```

with

```
gcc -c *.c
gcc -o test.bin ./*.o
```

While getting this output

```
3214954436 
123
```

the first number is changing every time I run test.bin

What am I missing here?

Comment: `printf(fmt, args);` is the culprit, you are passing `args` instead of `va_arg(args, int)`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - And an exact one too. I have not idea how I missed that. But I would not list the second one there myself. The question isn't about that, really.

Comment: @StoryTeller well it goes along there :D

Comment: But yea, perhaps not necessary